# Merge two data frames with different dimensions with partial overwrite in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I've spent the better part of a day on this but I keep getting stuck. This wouldn't take me very long using index-match-match in Excel, but I'm newer to R and merging data doesn't seem very straight-forward. I've searched the site and found similar problems but no solutions specific to this type of issue.

I have two data frames. They have different lengths in both dimensions. `a` is 4x4 and `b` is 3x3. They partially overlap:

```
a <- data.frame("ID" = c(1:4), "A" = c(21:24), "B" = c(31:34), "C" = c(41:44))
a

  ID  A  B  C
1  1 21 31 41
2  2 22 32 42
3  3 23 33 43
4  4 24 34 44
```

and

```
b <- data.frame("ID" = c(4:6), "C" = c(22:24), "D" = c(32:34))
b
  ID  C  D
1  4 22 32
2  5 23 33
3  6 24 34
```

I'm merging on "ID" number. My goal is to get them to look like

```
c <- data.frame("ID" = c(1:6), "A" = c(21:24, NA, NA), "B" = c(31:34, NA, NA), "C" = c(41:43,22:24), "D" = c(NA, NA, NA, 32:34))
c

 ID  A  B  C  D 
 1   21 31 41 NA 
 2   22 32 42 NA 
 3   23 33 43 NA 
 4   24 34 22 32 
 5   NA NA 23 33 
 6   NA NA 24 34
```

As you can see, the final data frame combines the two and assigns NA to the missing information. In column "C", I would like `b` to overwrite `a` where it has numerical values. In this example, the value in `c[4,3]` should change from 44 to 22.

Most of this is simple enough. But getting column "C" correct has been a nightmare. I did the simple thing first:

```
merge(a, b, by = "ID", all = T)
```

It almost does the trick but ends up with duplicate row "C"s:

```
  ID  A  B C.x C.y  D
1  1 21 31  41  NA NA
2  2 22 32  42  NA NA
3  3 23 33  43  NA NA
4  4 24 34  44  22 32
5  5 NA NA  NA  23 33
6  6 NA NA  NA  24 34
```

This wouldn't be so bad if I could find out how to merge the duplicate rows correctly because then I could just run

```
merge(a[-4], b[-2], by = "ID", all = T)
  ID  A  B  D
1  1 21 31 NA
2  2 22 32 NA
3  3 23 33 NA
4  4 24 34 32
5  5 NA NA 33
6  6 NA NA 34
```

to merge everything else, then bring in the merged "C" after the fact.

But I can't figure it out how to deal with this part of it:

```
merge(a[c(1,4)], b[c(1,2)], by = "ID", all = T)
  ID C.x C.y         ID C
1  1  41  NA      1  1  41
2  2  42  NA      2  2  42
3  3  43  NA  ->  3  3  43
4  4  44  22      4  4  22
5  5  NA  23      5  5  23
6  6  NA  24      6  6  24
```

There's gotta be way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: BTW, the above data frames are examples, which you likely realized. The actual data frames I'm trying to merge are roughly 2000x100 and 200x20, so manually changing the single element won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
starthere <- merge(a, b, by = "ID", all = T)
starthere %>% 
  mutate(C = ifelse(is.na(C.y), C.x, C.y)) %>% 
  select(-C.x, -C.y)


  # ID  A  B  D  C
# 1  1 21 31 NA 41
# 2  2 22 32 NA 42
# 3  3 23 33 NA 43
# 4  4 24 34 32 22
# 5  5 NA NA 33 23
# 6  6 NA NA 34 24
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot! This appears to work great. I've begun studying dplyr recently so this will help me begin to understand it. Thanks again. I should be able to generalize this to suit by needs.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else looking at this in the future, I realized this could also be solved using the following in `base` rather than `dplyr`:

```
df <- merge(a, b, by = "ID", all = T)
df[,"C"] <- ifelse(is.na(df[,"C.y"]), df[,"C.x"], df[,"C.y"])
df <- df[,-c(match("C.x", names(df)),match("C.y", names(df)))]
```

This ended up being the method I used because down the road I came to needing to perform some steps that were very difficult with `dplyr` for a novice (using variables inside `mutate()` and `select()`) and much more straightforward in `base` using the above syntax.

Thanks again to CPak, without whom I could not have figured this out.